# Using sed to substitute string

Tags: sed

There are two bash variables in the script which I am building

```
num1=site_2734
num2=796
```

It needs to read an svg file containing the string:

```
http://xxx-xxx.xxx.com/var/site_2734/storage/issues/796/svg/img/page-002-img1.jpg?q=80
```

I want to replace the first part with 'nothing' and remove the '?q=10' so it becomes

```
page-002-img1.jpg
```

So I've tried something like this with sed which isn't working

```
sed -i -e 's/\(http:\/\/xxx-xxx.xxx.com\/var\/$num1\/storage\/issues\/$num2\/svg\/img/\).*\(\)/\1\2/'
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: The `'` prevent the shell from expanding `$num1`/`$num2`, try `"` instead.

Comment: It might be helpful to learn how not to build fences when working with `sed` commands.  Which is easier to read:  `s/\/this\/or\/that/theother/` or `s_this/or/that_theother_`? (:

Comment: Why don't we use awk instead of sed...

Answer (score 2):

Simple enough so long as the filename itself is known to never contain slashes or question marks:

```
sed --in-place 's_http.*/img/\(.*\)?q=[0-9][0-9]*_\1_' inputfile
```

If you really do need the site and issue numbers, you can assemble your `sed` command, and then implement it as a variable:

```
sedcmd='s_http.*'$num1'.*'$num2'.*/img/\(.*\)?q=[0-9][0-9]*_\1_'
sed --in-place "$sedcmd" inputfile
```

Comment: The url in the first comment above points to the whole svg file, I want to replace the string as detailed in the original question, so where it says [link](http://cdn-assets.ziniopro.com/var/site_2734/storage/issues/796/svg/img/page-002-img1.jpg?q=80) I want to change it to "page-002-img1.jpg?q=80" - but two variables need to be passed in to make sure the string matches exactly as above. This is to make the svg render the background image locally and not fetch it from the website above.

Comment: I have modified the expression to not expect the URL to be the entire input line as the question initially implied.

Comment: Thanks, I apologise if it wasn't that clear.